# Threads and Servers in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

Just when I thought I figured it out how threads work in Java, I was wrong.I want this server to listen for clients but at the same time allow me to input text on the console.

```
public class MultiThreadChatServerSync implements Runnable{

    private static ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    private static Socket clientSocket = null;
    private static final int maxClientsCount = 10;
    private static final clientThread[] threads = new clientThread[maxClientsCount];

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int portNumber = 2222;
        if (args.length < 1) {
            System.out.println("Usage<portNumber>\n");

        } else {
            portNumber = Integer.valueOf(args[0]).intValue();
        }

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        //I thought this was the answer and it would run in the backround
        (new Thread(new MultiThreadChatServerSync())).start();


    }
    public void run() {

        while (true) {
            try {
                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                int i = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
                    if (threads[i] == null) {
                        (threads[i] = new clientThread(clientSocket, threads)).start();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (i == maxClientsCount) {
                    PrintStream os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                    os.println("Server too busy. Try later.");
                    os.close();
                    clientSocket.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Please.What am I missing?

Comment: Please don't just repeat your own questions - it will not help you get an answer.  If you're not getting an answer that helps, edit the original question to clarify what you need.

Comment: @Don Roby.I apologise.Will do so next time.Just that I dont know what I am missing and tried very hard to get it but I dont.

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't very clear but I would suggest that the problem is that you are running your server on the main thread whilst attempting to accept user input from the console. If you want to still accept user input I would suggest having another thread thats sole purpose is to listen for and accept incoming connections.

In other words the kind of architecture you are looking at should be (pseudo code)

A server thread:

```
public void run() {
    while (connections < maxConnections) { 
        conn = accept connection

        // pass the new connection to a seperate thread
        sht = new ServerHelperThread(conn) 
        sht.start()
        connections++
    }
}
```

A server helper thread to deal with individual clients:

```
public ServerHelperThread(conn) {
    this.conn = conn;
}

public void run() {
    while(some condition) {
        communicate with client
    }
    conn.close()
}
```

A main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ServerThread().start
    accept input from the console
}
```

Comment: You are correct.My question was pretty vague.I have a client script and they can communicate with the server fine.Thats not the Problem.My Problem is this Line"clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();".It doesnt allow me to enter any input and I would like to enter input on the server as to send messages to all clients connected.The thread I tried to create was so that it can listen for clients on the background and allow me to input on the "server console".Please let me know if I am still vague.Thanks

Comment: what message do you want to send, please give me a bit more detail bullet points if you can

Comment: I have a client script that allows clients to send messages to each other, But I want more feautures. 1) Be able to type on the server while it waits for connections in order to send messages to connected clients.(One might say as admin). 2) My Problem: When the server is listening.It cannot accept input(I cannot write the messages). 3) I want the server to accept clients in the backround, this line"clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();" should happen in the background and not in the console because it blocks my input.

Comment: Thats because it's a blocking call method - it will wait forever to accept a client. I suggest you re-read my answer and code your server in the architecture I recommended. Then use the main class to accept your input from the console, this could then call a method from the ServerThread which calls a method from each of its ServerHelperThread children to send out the message to each client.